# What is error in my code ?? I Want Retrieve Customer Information using

Tags: php, ios, curl, paypal-sandbox

Profile Sharing Server-Side Integration (PayPal-iOS-SDK)

Retrieve Customer Information Using a Valid Access Token. but it is  not working (customer Information not fetch what is issue in my code. if any idea and code please help me )

```
$access_token = "xxxx";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/userinfo/?schema=openid");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Content-Type:application/json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Authorization: Bearer ".$access_token);

$result1 = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
print_r($result1);die;
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you read the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). **Also, I think you may now need to change your access token due to possible security issues...**

Comment: please tell me what is your confusion in my questions

Comment: any one please give answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$access_token = "xxxxx";


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/userinfo?schema=openid&access_token=xxxx");
$headers = array("Accept: application/json", "Accept-Language: en_US");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Authorization: Bearer ".str_replace(" ", "", $access_token));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);



$result1 = curl_exec($ch);
$information = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($information);die;
```

https://gist.github.com/xcommerce-gists/4007896#file-getuserprofile-request-curl

Comment: Welcome you syon dev